# web3.utils.toBN vs new web3.utils.BN

Tags: web3js

From [the document](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#utils-tobn) toBN is safer than new BN. However, given the same hex hash string, it results in something different:

```
(new web3.utils.BN('0x149e7b36b314b81fbe1762060fcae0f43be82f1251166a61fc7669e7c236c4bf')).toString()
// results in: '331504813713151826241762061631415442483512511670626276704822372525'

web3.utils.toBN('0x149e7b36b314b81fbe1762060fcae0f43be82f1251166a61fc7669e7c236c4bf').toString()
// results in: '9326269197397511364330713577831447135626556432227477146325167069213775807679'
```

Now I'm wondering which one should I use for hex string?

**EDIT**

For non-hex string, it creates the same value:

```
(new web3.utils.BN('57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968')).toString()
// results in: '57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968'

web3.utils.toBN('57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968').toString()
// results in: '57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968'
```

Answer (score 0):

- `web3.utils.BN` interprets the "ascii" string as if each character belongs to a number in an arbitrary base following the hex char notation 0xa = 10 and so on (I'm unsure about if someone is uses that) : `(new web3.utils.BN('x')).toString()` -> '33' .
- on the other hand, `web3.utils.toBN` is giving the expected result.